# To Auto-Populate Fields in Excel Using a Drop-Down with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Actually I am trying to select the dropdown value from the list , at first it will be empty so gives me error code of 1004 so I handle that error with the message box "Please Select The Address." But as soon as I select OK it again pops up because of the Call addressDropdown making the dropdown list not selectable.

```
 Sub addressDropdown()
 
 On Error GoTo ErrMsg
 
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=Customers!$A$2:$A$9"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
 
    End With
    
    If Len(Range("B7").Value) > 0 Then
 
    Range("B6").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B7"), Worksheets("Customers").Range("A1:D41"), 2, 0)
    Range("B8").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B7"), Worksheets("Customers").Range("A1:D41"), 3, 0)
    Range("B10").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B7"), Worksheets("Customers").Range("A1:D41"), 4, 0)
 
    Else
 
     End If
 
ErrMsg:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
Err.Clear
MsgBox "Please Select The Address."
Call addressDropdown
End If
End Sub
```

So I want to select the dropdown value from the list in order to get the true condition for the below

```
If Len(Range("B7").Value) > 0
```

then filling up the values for the ranges as below;

```
Range("B6").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B7"), Worksheets("Customers").Range("A1:D41"), 2, 0)
    Range("B8").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B7"), Worksheets("Customers").Range("A1:D41"), 3, 0)
    Range("B10").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B7"), Worksheets("Customers").Range("A1:D41"), 4, 0)
```

I have tried days and hours for achieving this but unable to get the desired solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Wait and Sleep methods is that the I cannot do anything in Excel
while waiting for the macro to continue.

To overcome this problem, I have used a loop with a method called DoEvents
before Call addressDropdown.

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 2500
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing row " & i
        DoEvents
Next i
```

And Finally I have got enough time to select the dropdown and select the
desired value.